# when I run xrandr on the same machine under ubuntu gnome desktop or i3 I get two different display lists - why?

Tags: ubuntu, i3, xrandr

- I am running a system76 ubuntu laptop
- I am trying to get 2 external monitors to play nicely with this laptop
- When booting into the machine with no external monitors all is fine/ normal in all cases
- When booting into ubuntu gnome desktop the monitors all play fine, with the right max resolutions, etc
- When booting in with i3, I cannot yet get it to work correctly at the correct max resolution (this is an independent question I think)
- When I run `xrandr` under ubuntu gnome desktop, I get a listing of just 2 external displays labelled `WAYLAND0` and `WAYLAND1` (which is accurate)
- When I run `xrandr` under i3, I get a long list of other display names (e-DP-1, DP-1-1, etc).

**The question**
Given the above, why does xrandr behave differently under these 2 different environments?

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Duh. ubuntu gnome desktop is using Wayland, not X11

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland